# Why url is set in $_GET when i use post method

Tags: forms, post, get

have you guys any ideas why the url is set in the $_GET, when i submit a form with post method?

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="/test/show/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="product" value="testing">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" value="go" name="submit">
</form>
```

In my chrome i can see it will be send as post, but if i do this:

```
if (count($_GET) > 0) {
    var_dump($_GET);
}
```

I get this result:

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> string(10) "test/show/" }
```

and i have no idea why?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, with that URL, it wouldn't be. Presumably you are using `mod_rewrite` or similar to map `/test/show` onto something like `/index.php?url="%2Ftest%2Fshow`.

This is because PHP picked poor names for the `$_GET` superglobals.

An HTML form with `method="GET"` will put the data from its form controls in the query string, but that isn't the only way to request a URL with a query string.

`$_GET` contains data from the query string **irrespective of the request method**.

Comment: Yes, i redirect everything threw my index.php. Is that the reason and what can i do to solve it?

Comment: Solve it? There's no sign of a problem. You don't solve it. You ignore it.

Comment: With other words, there is no chance to get an empy $_GET, when i send a form by post method?

Comment: Sure there is. You just need a URL without a query string on it. As mentioned, you appear to have some URL rewriting going on that adds a query string between the request arriving at your HTTP server and being processed by your PHP. The existence of a query string should not be a problem.

Comment: Thank you, found it! That what my RewriteRule looked like: RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]